# Fatal error when trying to compile C++: cannot open file 'kernel.32.lib'

Tags: c++

I am totally new to C++ and just finished setting it up with Visual Studio and VSCode, however, when I try to do
`cl file.cpp` in the file directory, I am returned an error:`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'`.
I have seen some similar queries across the site, but they either reference old versions of Visual Studio (I'm using 2019) so I haven't managed to fix the issue.
I have seen something saying that the file should be stored in the same location as the compiler but they currently aren't because the Compiler is on a small drive and want to keep the code on a larger drive.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ***they either reference old versions of Visual Studio*** The solution is probably the same.

Comment: ***I have seen something saying that the file should be stored in the same location as the compiler but they currently aren't because the Compiler is on a small drive and want to keep the code on a larger drive*** This is not a correct statement. I have my compiler on C: and source code on X: for the last 20+ years and many many versions of Visual Studio.